# How can I build a large LED screen?

Tags: led, led-matrix

I'm trying to make an LED screen. I have 1088AS LED matrix (8x8).

http://www.ebay.ch/itm/MAX7219-Microcontroller-4-In-1-Display-with-5P-Line-Dot-Matrix-Module-Arduino-/282073774611?

With an Arduino I can control each LED for the 4 LED screens. Can I add an infinity number of others matrix? Have I a maximum?

I want to build a screen 1m / 2 meter.

If not possible, have you another solution to build that?

Comment: Regardless of the physical size, how many pixels total do you want to control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX7219 is a driver for up to 8x8 LEDs. It needs a single-bit data input, a bit clock and a frame clock input. As that display module already has four 8x8 LED matrices, it most likely has 4 data inputs, a bit clock and a frame clock. So, 6 GPIOs. For each of those modules, you need another GPIO for a separate bit clock, and this will divide the possible frame rate of the screen by two. But as the MAX7219 supports up to 10Mbit/s data rate, it shouldn't be a problem to arrange numerous of those modules to one big screen.

EDIT: I have to correct myself, the MAX7219 also has a data **output**, so that module most likely needs only 3 GPIOS. And one should use the "frame clock" (LOAD input) to separate modules, not the bit clock.